# TIdHTTP - Get only Responsecode

Tags: delphi, indy, delphi-10.1-berlin

I am using the `TIdHTTP` component and it's `GET` function.

The `GET` function sends a complete request, which is fine.

However I would like to spare/save some traffic from a GET response and only want to receive the Responsecode which is in the first "line" of a HTTP response.

Is there a possibility of disconnecting the connection in order to save traffic from any further content?

As mentioned, I only need the responsecode from a website.

I alternatively thought about using Indy's TCP component (with SSL IOHandler) and craft an own HTTP Request Header and then receive the responsecode and disconnect on success - but I don't know how to do that.

Comment: That's what the Head request is for, or am I missing something here?

Comment: @DNR I didn't know about this function. Thank you for the hint, however this function sends a HEAD request but I need it to be a GET request

Comment: A HEAD request is the same as a GET request, only that it doesn't send the response content. Isn't that just what you want?

Comment: @DNR The HEAD request is NOT a GET request... The webserver I am trying a HEAD request results in 405 not allowed response. That's why it needs to be a GET request in the first place and all I need is the first few bytes of the webserver's response.

Comment: @DNR what about the TIdTCPClient component? I could just craft my own HTTP request header, send it receive the first few bytes and disconnect as soon as I got my result. I just don't know how to do that, since I have never used this component.

Comment: At a minimum (HTTP is a complex protocol), you could do something like this: `IdTCPClient1.Host := 'www.domain.com'; IdTCPClient1.Port := 80{443 for SSL}; IdTCPClient1.Connect; {for SSL: (IdTCPClient1.IOHandler as TIdSSLIOHandlerSocketBase).PassThrough := False;} IdTCPClient1.IOHandler.Write('GET /resource HTTP/1.1'#13#10'Host: www.domain.com'#13#10'Connection: close'#13#10#13#10); Response := IdTCPClient1.IOHandler.ReadLn; IdTCPClient1.Disconnect; // parse Response as needed ... `

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`TIdHTTP` has an `OnHeadersAvailable` event that is intended for this very task. It is triggered after the response headers have been read and before the body content is read, if any.  It has a `VContinue` output parameter that you can set to False to cancel any further reading.

---

**Update**: Something I just discovered: When setting `VContinue=False` in the `OnHeadersAvailable` event, `TIdHTTP` will set `Response.KeepAlive=False` and skip reading the response body (OK so far), but after the response is done being processed, `TIdHTTP` checks the `KeepAlive` value, and the property getter returns True if the socket hasn't been closed on the server's end (HTTP 1.1 uses keep-alives by default).  This causes `TIdHTTP` to not close its end of the socket, and will leave any response body unread.  If you then re-use the same `TIdHTTP` object for a new HTTP request, it will end up processing any unread body data from the previous response before it sees thee response headers of the new request.

You can work around this issue by setting the `Request.Connection` property to `'close'` before calling `TIdHTTP.Get()`.  That tells the server to close its end of the socket connection after sending the response (although, I just found that when requesting an HTTPS url, especially after an HTTP request directs to HTTPS, `TIdHTTP` clears the `Request.Connection` value!).  Or, simply call `TIdHTTP.Disconnect()` after `TIdHTTP.Get()` exits.

I have now updated `TIdHTTP` to:

- no longer clear the `Request.Connection` when preparing an HTTPS request.
- close its end of the socket connection if either:

  - `OnHeadersAvailable` returns `VContinue=False`
  - the `Request.Connection` property (or, if connected to a proxy, the `Request.ProxyConnection` property) has been set to `'close'`, regardless of the server's response.

Comment: Is there any way to flush the buffer within OnHeadersAvailable? I am using about 50 threads on the same target address with this event. The TIdHeaderList gives me body content for some reason and no header data at all. All threads have their own TIdHTTP Instance and their own OnHeadersAvailable event. Any Ideas why it shows me some weird body content? Response code is sometimes -1

Comment: When `OnHeadersAvailable` is fired, `TIdHTTP` hasn't read the body content yet (though it may have been read from the socket and buffered in the `IOHandler.InputBuffer` waiting to be read). The only way I can see body content appearing in the `TIdHeaderList` is if you are doing something to make `TIdHTTP` skip the body content without closing the socket, and then you read another HTTP request on the same socket connection.  It would read the pending body content instead of the next request headers. If `OnHeadersAvailable` returns `VContinue=False`, `TIdHTTP` should be closing the socket.

Comment: I am using VContinue:=False; and the response code get's buggy when I use multiple TIdHTTP instances within a thread. The less threads I use, the more I get the right results (response code). Will investigate this further and may make a new question to this topic. However, your answer is accepted is best suited for this situation.

Comment: I updated my answer. Turns out there were some bugs in `TIdHTTP` that I have now fixed.

Answer (score 2):

Usually you would use `TIdHttp.Head`, because HEAD requests are intended for doing just that.

If the server does not accept HEAD requests like in OP's case, you can assign the `OnWorkBegin` event of your `TIdHttp` instance, and call `TIdHttp(Sender).Disconnect;` there. This immediately closes the connection, the download does not continue, but you still have the meta data like response code, content length etc.

Comment: Thank you for the answer. Could you please give me an example? I am not familiar with OnWorkBegin seems to be called when already the content has been completely downloaded.

Comment: No it isn't. That's OnWorkEnd. You just assign the event handler, and the only line you have to put in it is the Disconnect call.

Comment: This is a great answer! Thank you very much. I did also set the Receive Buffer Size to 1 so I save 32kb :)

Comment: Note that you are disconnecting the socket behind `TIdHTTP`'s back, so be prepared to handle the resulting exception when `TIdHTTP` tries to read from a closed connection.

Comment: @Benjamin Weiss I think you should accept Remy's answer, the effect is round about the same, but his is more elegant.

Comment: @DNR: well, not only that, but what I described is how `TIdHTTP` is actually *designed* to be used, whereas your approach is a workaround.